# Get the char that would be typed on `XKB_KEY_dead_circumflex` and normal key

Tags: linux, keyboard, x11

Is there a way to determine in which character it would resolv e.g. if I would type `XKB_KEY_dead_circumflex` and char `a`? The result here would be `â`, but how can I detect this programmatically?

This not only applies to `XKB_KEY_dead_circumflex`, but e.g. also to `XKB_KEY_dead_greek` to type the greek alphabet.

Comment: Create an invisible window and send keypress events to it.

Answer (score 1):

In X, this particular behaviour is determined by the Input Method (IM). X is very flexible; you could write an input method that combines `XKB_KEY_dead_circumflex` and `a` into Japanes `キ` if you like. Or output an `è`, if you want to confuse your users...

You could try XmbLookupString or Xutf8LookupString to simulate keypresses and return the correct character:

```
XIM im= XOpenIM(display, NULL, NULL, NULL);
XIC ic = XCreateIC(im);

char buf[8];
KeySym symbol;
Status status;
XKeyPressedEvent event;
event.type = XKeyPressEvent;
event.display = display;
event.window = window;
event.state = 0; // optionally add Shift, Ctrl, Meta
event.keycode = XBK_KEY_dead_circumflex;
Xutf8LookupString(ic, &event, buf, 8, symbol, status); // send dead key
event.keycode = XBK_KEY_a;
Xutf8LookupString(ic, &event, buf, 8, symbol, status); // send real key
```

`buf` should now contain the UTF8 code for `â`, but check `status` to see if the transformation succeeded.

Note that you have to pass the keycode for 'a', not the ASCII code for 'a' (I don't think there is any X function that takes a dead key and a character and returns the combination). You must also simulate only KeyPresses (see the manual page for Xutf8LookupString).

Comment: Does not work :(. as a result I get after the first call a "^" and after the second an "a"

Comment: Is there an XFilterEvent() in your main event loop? That's important in this case...

Comment: I dunno. I use GTK for the GUI stuff

Comment: `Xutf8LookupString` is stateless.